# NuGet packageSources priority

Tags: nuget

If you have multiple packageSources in your NuGet.config:

```
<packageSources>
  <clear />
  <add key="dev" value="http://server2/branches/feature1/nuget" />
  <add key="release" value="http://server1/nuget" />
</packageSources>
```

Is the order in the XML used when running nuget install, etc? If I have packageA at version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in both, will the dev channel version on feature1 branch win?

Answer (score 2):

The order of your feeds in nuget.config determines the order that they show up in the drop down menus from the various views into NuGet from Visual Studio.  In all cases, you have the choice of which feed you install from.   See the screenshots below.

Visual Studio doesn't keep track of where your package came from, so the package ID is really in a global namespace that you have to know which feed it's a part of.  Visual Studio will show you any package from the selected feed with a matching ID, so it's possible that you'd overwrite a package you installed from one feed with another from a different feed.

For a NuGet feed that I manage at my company, I prefix our internal packages with `<CompanyName>.` so as to reduce the risk for a naming conflict now and in the future.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am actually trying to override based on the order, actually. This way packages that were built on a feature branch get higher priority, based on the packageSources. This way, http://ourserver/featurebranch1/nuget will contain the same package names, just built against a specific branch. This way we won't need to change our dependencies outright. If a package is missing from the feature feed, it will pull from the regular mainline feed.

Comment: Could you just have a different nuget.config file checked in to your feature branch?  That way you can specify a "release feed" for those branches and a "development feed" in Trunk, for example.

Comment: So what happens when I run nuget restore from the command line which source will it use if a packages is in both sources?

Comment: @red888 
For all intents and purposes at restore time, the fastest source wins. 

If possible, I'd avoid relying on priority order. 
The priority ordering caused performance issues, as the calls to the sources were sequential instead of parallel.

Comment: Isn't this a security risk? What happens if someone managed to publish a package with YourCompanyName.NugetPackage to the public nuget feed? Is there a chance that a malicious package does get installed?

Comment: This is indeed a security risk.  How has nuget not implemented either a source priority or package reference level source specification?