# Nuget package from specific package source on nuget restore step on Azure

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package-restore

The package I am trying to restore is both on `nuget.org` and on a `3rd party myget`. The 3rd party is a higher version (pre-release) that I want to use, however it seems to not even try to locate the myget source for this package since it finds the package on nuget.org except not the version I want resulting in the following error message:

```
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Errors in packages.config projects
Unable to find version '2.0.0-dev-00013' of package 'Discord.Addons.Interactive'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'Discord.Addons.Interactive.2.0.0-dev-00013' is not found on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.)
```

The myget is properly configured in my nuget.config, which is in my solution root

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="Foxbot" value="https://www.myget.org/F/foxbot-discord-addons/api/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

How would I go about making the nuget restore step respect the myget package source for this package?

Comment: Hi Perry, how do you configure the nuget restore task in build pipeline? As I know, to make nuget.config work in build pipeline, we should set `Nuget.config` as our feeds, or it won't work though this file is in Solution directory. (This is something different from restore locally.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I go about making the nuget restore step respect the myget
>   package source for this package?

For `nuget restore` task, there's one option used to control which feeds to use during package restore.

See **feeds to use**:

[image]

**Different from** restoring packages **locally**, the `nuget.config` file in solution directory(Devops Repos) won't work until we check the `Feeds in my Nuget.config` option.

So during that process, nuget actually didn't use your `nuget.config` file for `package source`, which caused this issue:

[image]

**Workaround:**

Configure the Feeds in my `Nuget.config` like below to make sure nuget will use your `Nuget.config` file in Solution directory:

[image]

**In addition:** If you're using [yaml format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema) instead of classic format, you should set `feedsToUse: 'config'` and `nugetConfigPath: 'path/NuGet.config'`.

Comment: I completely missed the option to actually select the nuget.config file in the restore task, I thought it respected that automatically. Maybe I shouldn't work on these things before going to bed, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There is no longer a priority for sources, the fastest one wins.

Packages are expected to be unique on the id and version, scenarios where feeds contain different variations of the same id/version are NOT supported.

The priority ordering caused performance issues, as the calls to the sources were sequential instead of parallel.  I would suggest you the following to resolve this issue:

- avoid having different packages with the same id/version, or to reconcile these issues before hand by using a single feed where this has already been resolved.
- Add a prefix/suffix in the custom feed source

If still requires the priority , you could so something like below:
Have config something like below:

```
  <packageSources>
        <!-- Internal package source comes before NuGet.org proxy -->   
        <add key="my_private_feed" value="Feed1/" priority="1" />
        <add key="Orgnugetorg" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" priority="2" />
    </packageSources>
```

The `**PackageDownloader**` needs to be adapted that he waits for the download with the highest priority if package sources have different priorities otherwise fastest wins,

But please be mindful that it would require change in Packagedownloader in your pipeline.

Additional reference:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5611

[NuGet packageSources priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36470532/nuget-packagesources-priority)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I got here needing to stomp a broken package on nuget.org with a large number of dependencies. Oof.